# error cs1729 doesnt contain a constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, compiler-errors

The same code works in 1 proj and not in other. Any other way to write this.
Error I am getting is error CS1729: 'Assessment' does not contain a constructor that takes 12 arguments.    The same when I copy into a diff proj it compiles and works well. Tried cleaning temporary asp.net files, but doesn't help.

```
public class Assessment
{ 
   public Assessment(Guid assessmentId,string applicationId,string assessmentType,   Guid requestedBy,DateTime requestedDate,Guid assessmentOwner,string applicationToTest,
bool isCompleted,DateTime dateScheduled,DateTime datePerformed, GuidperformedBy,       string uri)
   {
        this.AssessmentId = assessmentId;      this.ApplicationId = applicationId;
        this.AssessmentType = assessmentType;  this.RequestedBy = requestedBy;
        this.RequestedDate = requestedDate;    this.AssessmentOwner = assessmentOwner;
        this.ApplicationToTest = applicationToTest; this.IsCompleted = isCompleted;
        this.DateScheduled = dateScheduled;    this.DatePerformed = datePerformed;
        this.PerformedBy = performedBy;        this.uri = uri;

   }

   public Assessment()
   {
        this.AssessmentId = Guid.NewGuid();    this.ApplicationId = string.Empty;
        this.AssessmentType = string.Empty;    this.RequestedBy = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.RequestedDate = DateTime.Now;     this.AssessmentOwner = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.ApplicationToTest = string.Empty; this.IsCompleted = false;
        this.DateScheduled = Convert.ToDateTime(DateScheduled);
        this.DatePerformed = Convert.ToDateTime(DatePerformed);
        this.PerformedBy = Guid.NewGuid();   this.uri = string.Empty;

   }
 public Guid AssessmentId  { get;     set;  }                
 public string ApplicationId   {get;  set;  }               
 public string AssessmentType  {get;  set;  }                
 public Guid RequestedBy  { get;    set;   }                
 public DateTime RequestedDate {get; set;  }
 public Guid AssessmentOwner  {get; set;  }
 public string ApplicationToTest {get; set;  }                
 public bool IsCompleted  { get;  set;  }
 public DateTime DateScheduled  {get; set;   }              
 public DateTime DatePerformed  { get;  set; }
 public Guid PerformedBy { get;  set;  }
 public string uri  { get; set; }
}


aspx.cs
  protected void bnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Assessment asst = new Assessment(Guid.Parse(AssessmentId.Text),
           txtApplicationID.Text,
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue,
            requestedBy,
            DateTime.Now,
            Guid.Parse(txtAssessmentOwnerEmail.Text),
            ddlApplicationToTest.SelectedValue,
            false,
            CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault(),
            CalendarExtender2.SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault(),
            Guid.Parse(txtPerfomedBy.Text),
            txtUri.Text);
    db.AddAssessment(asst);
  }
```

Comment: go ahead and add the missing `}` and see what happens.

Comment: sorry where } is missing. That one closes after get set. I dint post as it will be long

Comment: The code is fine so try to restart your VS.

Comment: In case nobody else mentions it, 12 arguments is one heck of a code smell.

Answer (score 3):

Things to look into:

1. Are there any other class definitions named `Assessment` in other namespaces?
2. Check your project references.  Make sure you're referencing the assembly that contains the correct `Assessment` definition.  You could unknowingly be referencing an old version of that assembly.
3. Use a disassembler such as ILSpy to inspect the assembly containing `Assessment`.  Verify it contains the correct class definition.

Answer (score 0):

The code posted shows the start of an `Assessment` class.  There is no closing `}` on that class.

Then there is a function call (which typically would be part of a page class) which creates a new Assessment class.

So my guess is this is two files that you joined parts of to explain your problem.  This means you did not include a using in the page class -- or have a typo in the name or are referencing a different file in your project.

It is also possible that Assessment class is not compiling, but there is a prior compiled version which is being linked to.

Something along these lines.  In any case this is not the exact code you are using so it is impossible for us to figure out what is the problem.  You could plop full code somewhere (bitbucket?) and then we could see what the problem is.

Comment: There is a closing }. Edited code.Please check . I too doubt that Assessment class is using prior compiled version. But I tried to rebuild several times. I dont find clean option.

Comment: @user2340141 ...and now it has 13 parameters, which would be consistent with the error message.